# Cannot install private Go module

Tags: git, go, go-modules

I have a private project which uses a private module at `github.com/company/company-product`. When I try to build the project, I get:

```
go: github.com/company/company-product@v1.0.4: reading github.com/company/company-product/go.mod at revision v1.0.4: unknown revision v1.0.4
```

Things I have tried:

- Checked that the tag exists
- `go env -w GO111MODULE=on`
- `go env -w GOPRIVATE=github.com/company/company-product`
- `export GOPRIVATE=github.com/company/*`
- `export GONOPROXY=github.com/company/*`
- `export GONOSUMDB=github.com/company/*`
- Configured git to use `ssh://git@github.com/` instead of `https://github.com/`
- Configured git to use `ssh://$PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN@github.com/` instead of `https://github.com/`
- Deleted everything in `$GOPATH/pkg`
- `go clean`
- `go mod download`, `go mod tidy`, `go mod vendor` (which all produce the above error)
- Restarted my computer
- Connected to my company's VPN

And yet I still get the same error.

Comment: At first glance it seems like the tag `v1.0.4` doesn't exist. Has this been verified?

Comment: Yes, I have verified it exists.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the key was to do things in a certain order:

1. Reinstall Go
2. Set environment variables GOPRIVATE, GONOPROSXY, GONOSUMDB to `github.com/company/*`
3. Remove the folder `$GOPATH/pkg`
4. Setup Git to use `ssh://git@github.com/` instead of `https://github.com/`
5. Run `go get github.com/company/company-product`

Answer (score 0):

the solution which worked for me;

1. go env -w GOPRIVATE=github.com/company
2. git config --global url."https://username:accesstoken@github.com".insteadOf "https://github.com"
3. env GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1 go get github.com/company/privaterepo